# If Possible, how can I set multiple "data-anchor-target"s using skrollr?

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I tried recently using the tool skrollr for a website and I want to set multiple data anchor targets to get the website to do what is essentially the same animation more than once while scrolling downward based on the position of other elements. The reason this is necessary is because the other elements are sized by percentage (or relative to the height of the webpage). If there is a way to make skrollr trigger animations by the percentage rather than concrete placements on the website (like data-300="" etc.) that would also solve my problems.

Comment: You can't have duplicate attributes in a tag. There can only be one `data-anchor-target`.

Comment: K, I though this might be a limitation. Do you know if you can trigger animations by the percentage of the website you have traveled or an externally calculated number? Like 100% - 50px or something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with skrollr so I don't know its capabilities.

Comment: K, thanks anyways :)

Comment: I'm very new too.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, then that library always treats data- attribute values like JSON if they look like JSON.  Thus you could store a JSON array in a single such attribute. Whether that applies to "skrollr", I can't say.